# Gradle: Replace a dependency in an alternate build configuration

Tags: java, gradle

How do I create a new task in a gradle java project, which builds the project as normal, but swaps one of the compile time dependencies for a different library?

Comment: Is this question about how to (conditionally) swap a dependency, or specifically about how to do this with a task (and you already know how to swap dependencies in general)? Can you give some background on why/when the dependency needs to be swapped?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I am building a .NET .dll file with IKVM alongside the standard JAR. Part of the project needs to implement some .NET interfaces in the IKVM version of the build, and so is compiled against a library which contains stub types in order to make the Java compiler happy. However, the non-IKVM build must instead build against another library which contains standard Java implementations of these interfaces. I am not at all sure how to conditionally swap dependencies.

Comment: Are the libraries that need to be swapped out/in part of the same build, or are they external dependencies resolved from a repository?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser One of them is a project dependency in the same build, and another is a jar which is currently downloaded in another task, but could be resolved from a maven repository instead.

Comment: have you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no documented way to do this. The only workaround that comes to mind is to extract sources from your jar and connect them only in one flavor. In your build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
        flavor2 {
        }
        flavor1 {
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
        }

        flavor2 {
            java.srcDirs = ['path_to_your_lib_src']
        }

        flavor1 {
            java.srcDirs = ['path_to_your_jar_src']
        }
    }
}
```